# Is delivery of Azure Application Insights custom events guaranteed once TelemetryClient.TrackEvent() is called?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Microsoft states that the SLA for Application Insights is:

> We guarantee that the data latency of the Application Insights Service will not exceed two hours 99.9% of the time.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/application-insights/v1_0/

For the 0.1% of time outside the SLA, when TelemetryClient.TrackEvent() executes in my code, Is Microsoft guaranteeing that the event will definitely be published at some point (just not within 2 hours)? Or could the event be lost during that 0.1% time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, just calling TrackEvent doesn't *guarantee* it is published, for lots of reasons:

1. sampling at any level of the process. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sampling?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json but in general if sampling is on, some % of your events might be merged together.  there are various ways to find those events, but in general it is possible that if you call `trackMessage` 1000 times in a tight loop with the same content, an SDK might sample that and send a single event with itemCount set to 1000.
2. the content of the event could be invalid (to large a payload, exceeding thresholds for sizes of fields, too many custom properties, too many custom metrics, etc)
3. the time of the event could be invalid.  events too far in the past (>48h old?) or too far into the future (not sure the exact time there, but some future time is allowed to account for clock skew/drift)
4. caps - you could exceed the amount you're allowed to send per month - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-pricing, which at the time of this answer states:

   > The maximum cap is 1,000 GB/day unless you request a higher maximum for a high-traffic application.
5. throttling - you could exceed the allowed number of events per second/etc  - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-pricing, which at the time of this answer states:

   > Throttling limits the data rate to 32,000 events per second, averaged over 1 minute per instrumentation key.
6. network issues, etc. calling track on the various sdks doesn't guarantee the data is accepted or retried.  some of the sdks attempt to retry, some do not.
7. your application could shut down / crash between the call to `track` and the actual connection to application insights is created/completed.
8. other random issues, service issues, downtime of other dependent services, etc that account for that 0.1% of missing data.  I'm not sure there's any APM/telemetry service that guarantees it will accept and process 100% of the events you send.
   (100% - 99.9% is not 0.01%, it is 0.1%.  there's a 10x difference there.)

Answer (score 0):

I have escalated this issue to app insights team. If any feedback, I will update you.

As per my understanding, for the other 0.01% time outside SLA, if there is some downtime, the data would get lost. In any other condition, it would be published beyond 2 hours.

Hope it helps.